# Format SQL query in c++

Tags: c++, sql

I was wondering if there is something I can use in C++ similar to ["sqlparse" module in Python](http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/) to format my query. Do you know what can I use?

I'm sorry for didn't provide an example before.
I want that something like this:

```
SELECT MEMB.NAME, MEMB.AGE, AGE.GROUP FROM MEMB, AGE WHERE MEMB.AGE = AGE.AGE
```

Become this:

```
SELECT MEMB.NAME,
       MEMB.AGE,
       AGE.GROUP
FROM   MEMB,
       AGE
WHERE  MEMB.AGE = AGE.AGE
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For those of us who don't know what "sqlparse" is - format it in what way? Please provide an example.

Comment: Hmm, why not just write it that way then? Why do you need a tool? I would think the enter key and the space bar would be all the tools you need. I guess I'm missing the point of the question.

Comment: Well, I don't want to write any function that does that. First because the code is not mine and second because I don't code in c++. I just need a function that does that, like the format method in the module that I've mentioned before.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own pretty printer. In that case, it won't be any hard. Just replace things like the following:

```
"FROM" -> "\nFROM"
"WHERE" -> "\nWHERE"
"," -> ",\n\t"
"AND" -> "AND\n\t"
"OR" -> "OR\n\t"
```

etc.

Edit: as you don't code, here's a little version of this functionality.

```
#include <string>
using std::string; /* put these lines in the top of your file */

string replace(string a, string b, string c) {
    unsigned x;
    for(x = a.find(b); x != string::npos;) {
        a.erase(x, b.length());
    a.insert(x, c);
    }
    return a;
}




string formatSQL(string sql) {

    replace(sql, "FROM", "\nFROM");
    replace(sql, "WHERE", "\nWHERE");
    replace(sql, "," , ",\n\t");
    replace(sql, "AND", "AND\n\t");
    replace(sql, "OR", "OR\n\t");
}
```

So calling `formatSql("SELECT MEMB.NAME, MEMB.AGE, AGE.GROUP FROM MEMB, AGE WHERE MEMB.AGE = AGE.AGE")` gives you the desired result.